# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str Why list indexes are not numbers

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

with open('crawlingweb.csv')as f:
    content=f.readlines()
    content=[x.strip() for x in content]

for i in content:
    content[i].replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
    req = requests.get(content[i])
    html = req.text
    data = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z\\s\\.\\,]', '', string=html).lower()
    data = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', string=html)
    data = re.sub('[^ ㄱ-ㅣ가-힣]+', '', string=html)
    print(data)
```

content[i].replace('[', '').replace(']', '') this line was error
What I want is to repeat this code and crawl the entire address in the content once and print it out.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

with open('crawlingweb.csv')as f:
    content=f.readlines()
    content=[x.strip() for x in content]
    content[183].replace('[','').replace(']','')

req = requests.get(content[183])
html = req.text

data = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z\\s\\.\\,]', '', string=html).lower()
data = re.sub('<[^>]*>','',string=html)
data = re.sub('[^ ㄱ-ㅣ가-힣]+','',string=html)
print(data)
```

this code worked

thank you for reading

Answer (score 0):

Because

> ```
> with open('crawlingweb.csv')as f:               # this is a file
>     content=f.readlines()                       # this is a list of strings
>     content=[x.strip() for x in content]        # this is still a list of strings
>
> for i in content:                               # i is a string from your list
> ```

What you want is:

```
for index,line  in enumerate(content):
    # to replace the modified contentitem in content:
    content[index] = line.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
    req = requests.get(content[index])

    # or - to simply fix 'line' before doing your request:
    line = line.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
    req = requests.get(line)
```

or do it further up like so:

```
with open('crawlingweb.csv')as f:               
    content=f.readlines()                       
    content=[x.strip().replace('[', '').replace(']', '') for x in content]
```